# Showing a set of function is compact in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

I want to find out if the set of functions
$$S = \left \{ \exp \left ( \frac{1}{2} x^2 \right ) \frac{\mathrm{d} ^{4m}}{\mathrm{d} x ^{4m}} ( \exp(-x^2)) \ | \ m = 0,1,2,... \right \}$$
is compact in $L^2 (\mathbb{R}).$ I know that in order to do this we need to induce some topology on the set, so if we think about $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ as a reflexive Banach space, I think that can help but I am not sure. I am thinking there is a clever solution to this problem rather than just tedious computations, but again, I am not sure.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: [This theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_theorem) (a generalisation of Arzela-Ascoli's theorem to $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ spaces) might help you I think, though I do not know how easy/difficult it would be to apply here...

Comment: @BrunoB Thanks. Although it does become too difficult for me.